# log4j collision with multiple ejb containers

Tags: maven-2, log4j, ejb, glassfish-3

I have implemented several Java applications stored in EJB containers which I deploy on the same Glassfish domain. Each of them has it's own log4j.properties file located in the resources folder of each's application project (they are all Maven projects).

A different log file is configured in each log4j.properties file but when I deploy my applications they end up to write in the same log file.

Does anyone know how to resolve this problem? :)

EDIT: Here are my log4j.properties files for two projects.

The first:

```
log4j.rootLogger=ALL,AppFileAppender

log4j.appender.AppFileAppender=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender

log4j.appender.AppFileAppender.File=${com.sun.aas.instanceRoot}/logs/Engine.log

log4j.appender.AppFileAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.AppFileAppender.layout.ConversionPattern= %d [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n

log4j.logger.hesemulatorproducer=ALL,AppFileAppender
log4j.logger.org.hibernate=info
```

The second:

```
log4j.rootLogger=ALL,AppFileAppender

log4j.appender.AppFileAppender=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender

log4j.appender.AppFileAppender.File=${com.sun.aas.instanceRoot}/logs/SendEndDeviceEvents.log

log4j.appender.AppFileAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.AppFileAppender.layout.ConversionPattern= %d [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n

log4j.logger.hesemulatorproducer=ALL,AppFileAppender
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see comment link for this question. So I am asking few clarifications in this answer. These may help in finding root cause of the issue.

Can you please check the config file path and name, you specify while initializing Log4j?

Also, can you please give the file in which log is being printed for both projects? Is it server log or one of the application log file?

Are these projects being deployed in different WARs/EARs?

You can print repository location using org.apache.log4j.LogManager.getLoggerRepository().